# Reference to a column under a variable header of a table

Tags: excel, excel-tables

Given a table `T` and headers `H1`, `H2`, `H3`. I know that we can use `T[H1]` to refer to the column under the header `H1` of the table.

Now, I have a cell `A10` containing the header such as `H1`, `H2`, or `H3`. I would like to return the column depending the value of `A10`, does anyone know how to do that?

I tried `T[A10]`, Excel does not accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDIRECT("T["&A10&"]")
```

More on `INDIRECT`: [indirect](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)